# Duvida a respeito da exclamação dupla (!!) em javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vi a utilização da mesma no código fonte da *Jquery*, por exemplo:

```
fired: function() {
    return !!fired;
}
```

*Trecho de código localizado entre as linhas 3222 e 3224 da versão 2.1.4 uncompressed.*

---

- Ela é algo nativo de *Javascript* ou criada entre as funcionalidades da própria *Jquery*?
- Pode ser encontrada em outras linguagens, se sim quais por exemplo?

OBS.: gostaria de um exemplo da utilização na resposta.

**Pergunta reformulada após [discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4455/perguntas-duplicadas-com-votos-positivos-pode-isso.) do meta.**

Comment: -1 Essa pergunta já foi feita

Comment: Discussão no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4455/perguntas-duplicadas-com-votos-positivos-pode-isso

Comment: @DorivalZanetto isso pode acontecer, não tem qualquer problema. Desde que não comece a abrir duplicatas em série. TODA a gente já fez uma duplicata uma vez na vida.

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: [As duplicadas devem ser negativadas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378/as-duplicadas-devem-ser-negativadas)

Comment: Apenas uma nota para quem está chegando agora, o uso da dupla exclamação pode ser substituido pelo uso do Boolean: `Boolean(myVar)` ao invés de `!!myVar`

Answer (score 9):

Isso não pertence ao jQuery, isso é JavaScript mesmo. Quando você nega algo duas vezes, você está checando se um valor é o inverso de falso, experimente digitar no seu console: !'Olá Mundo', e teclar "enter", depois experimente isso: !!'Olá Mundo'; Depois experimente isso: `!![]+!![]`